# Possibility to know who created an instance on Azure

Tags: azure

Is it possible to know via portal or powershell which of the admins created new instances on azure or at least get alerts when something new is created?

Comment: No and no. You would have to poll yourself to figure out what changed.

Comment: You can (sort of) workaround it by creating multiple subscriptions for each of the admins (they get their budget from the same account). That way you can keep tabs on what your admins are creating.

Answer (score 0):

Things will get a little easier on the reporting end of Azure once all resources will be available through Resource Manager - http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/features/resource-manager/

Until then, for gaining more insight in what your co-admins created in your subscription, partners created solutions (cloudcruiser.com or cloudyn.com) for example.

Answer (score 0):

Resource Manager version of the portal is now available, so when creating resources everything is logged.  Any new stuff created using the classic version of the portal will of course not help in this situation, however even those powershell commands are being deprecated soon.  Hopefully this helps.